# Logging not executed upon redirect

Tags: java, spring-boot, redirect, logging, slf4j

In my Spring Boot 2.5.4 project, I have a GET method, that I have simplified into the example below.

**Problem:** When the method ends up executing the HTTP redirect... none of my log-lines end up writing to the log file (which works fine in the "error" scenario)... why?

The log property is derived from @Slf4j annotation on the class level.

```java
@GetMapping(value = "/login/{clientId}", produces = {"text/plain"})
public final ResponseEntity<String> login(@PathVariable String clientId,
                                               @RequestParam(required = false) String callbackUrl,
                                               HttpServletRequest httpRequest) {
    log.info("login called, clientId={}, callbackUrl={}", clientId, callbackUrl);

    // Validation:
    AppProperties.ClientInfo clientInfo = appProperties.getClientInfoById(clientId);
    if (clientInfo == null) {
        // 1: Does ClientID exist?
        log.warn("No ClientInfo found for clientId={}", clientId);
        return new ResponseEntity<>("No ClientInfo found for clientId=" + clientId, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }

    String redirectUrl = makeBrokerUrl(appProperties, clientInfo, callbackUrl, httpRequest);
    log.info("Redirect client to {}", redirectUrl);

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setLocation(URI.create(redirectUrl));
    return new ResponseEntity<>(headers, HttpStatus.valueOf(302));
}
```

**Update:**

- When I have clientId=1 configured, and call is /login/2 - I get both the info and the warn logging.
- When I call /login/1 I get NO logging at all - so yes: It is dependent on the execution of the redirect (as far as I see it).

Comment: This shouldn't be linked to whether you're redirecting or not. It could be a configuration issue, i.e. if your error logs work (I assume that's what your error scenario uses) then maybe everything below "error" severity (or "warn" if you refering to that) is filtered.

Comment: do you even get `log.info("login called` statement logged? Might be that log level is set to WARN and not INFO.

Comment: No, nothing is logged when redirect is executed... when I replace the redirect with simple text output, then logging is fine - sp it's not related to log level.